# Changing the name of an IBACTION now gives an uncaught exception error

Tags: coding-style, nsexception

OK this one is hopefully really simple

I thought I had it figured out once but can't remember what I did

In any app I go in and create a connection to a button or whatever and I give it a name like "PressThisButtonWhenDone"

this is all good and it works fine

BUT

I then want to change the name to "PressThisButtonWhenFinished"

so I delete the old action and create the new one with this name and I go into the .m file to remove the old action Xcode put in place automatically for me and place any code I had in the old method in the new properly named one.

I then build the project and it goes just fine the app comes up and I use all the other functions just fine and then I hit the Button associated with "PressThisButtonWhenFinished"
and I get something along these lines...

```
   2014-06-03 12:30:18.148 appname[5602:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<ViewController 0x12ed27d10> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key PressThisButtonWhenDone.'
   *** First throw call stack:
   (0x18cb66f50 0x1990701fc 0x18cb66bd4 0x18d624720 0x18cab25ec 0x18feeadd0 0x18fe2f878 0x18fb30488 0x18fb303f4 0x18fcdd868 0x18fbe7f54 0x18fbe7d24 0x18fbe7ca4 0x10241299c 0x18fb2aff8 0x18f71c258 0x18f716e20 0x18f716cd8 0x18f716560 0x18f716304 0x18fb2f16c 0x18cb27644 0x18cb269a0 0x18cb24c38 0x18ca65c20 0x19274dc0c 0x18fb96fdc 0x10009d6fc 0x199663aa0)
   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

This is the old button name and I cannot locate it anywhere to remove it 
I tried doing a clean not sure if that would do anything and it did nothing How do I eliminate this error

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out there was still a connection to the old name and that was the reason for the error.By going to the connections manager I found the new connection was there and so was the old one. I deleted the old one and it works fine now. I knew it would be a simple fix.